# How do i make this code to give expected result

Tags: javascript

```js
function myfun(){
   //var yofad = document.getElementById('age').value;
   var yoad;
   var year = 2014 ;
     if( year >= 2014){
        yoad = "Your certicate is ready go to school portal";
      } else if (year == 2019){
        yoad = "Your certificate is in progress";
      } else {
        yoad = "cert not found";
      }
document.getElementById('cc').innerHTML=yoad
}
```

```html
<h6>Enter your year of admission to know if your certificate is ready</h6>
<input id="age">
<button onclick="myfun()">enter</button>
<p id="xc"></p>
<p id="cc"></p>
```

I want the output to be "your certificate is ready go to school portal" when the input is between 2014 and 2019 and output should be cert is not read when the input is above 2019

Answer (score 2):

Limit your first condition to be less than 2019, otherwise for 2019 ,2020 and other greater values will be true as well.
change `if(year >= 14)` to `if(year >= 14 && year <2019)`

```js
function myfun(){
   var year = document.getElementById('age').value;
   var yoad;
     if( year >= 2014 && year < 2019){
        yoad = "Your certicate is ready go to school portal";
      } else if (year == 2019){
        yoad = "Your certificate is in progress";
      } else {
        yoad = "cert not found";
      }
document.getElementById('cc').innerHTML=yoad
}
```

```html
<h6>Enter your year of admission to know if your certificate is ready</h6>
<input id="age">
<button onclick="myfun()">enter</button>
<p id="xc"></p>
<p id="cc"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain the meaning of var year = document.getElementById('age').value;

Answer (score 2):

Just use and operatorit will help you to check 2 condition

```
function myfun(){
   //var yofad = document.getElementById('age').value;
   var yoad;
   var year = 2014 ;
     if( year >= 2014 && year <2019){
        yoad = "Your certicate is ready go to school portal";
      }else if (year == 2019){
       yoad = "Your certificate is in progress";
      } else {
        yoad = "cert not found";
      }
document.getElementById('cc').innerHTML=yoad
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myfun(){
  document.getElementById('cc').innerHTML = "";
  const value = document.getElementById('age').value;
  if (!value) return;
  
  const year = parseInt(value);
  let yoad;
  
  if (year > 2019) {
    yoad = "certicate not read";
  } else if (year >= 2014 && year <= 2019) {
    yoad = "Your certicate is ready go to school portal";
  } else {
    yoad = "cert not found";
  }
  
  document.getElementById('cc').innerHTML = yoad
}
```

```html
<h6>Enter your year of admission to know if your certificate is ready</h6>
<input id="age">
<button onclick="myfun()">enter</button>
<p id="xc"></p>
<p id="cc"></p>
```

You need something like this maybe!

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain a bit

Comment: Run the snippet and see if it works for you! No need to explain. I mean do you really want explanation?